# RStan: Use matrix in ordered_logistic()

Tags: stan, rstan

I would like to use `ordered_logistic()` function in RStan.

Firstly, here is the data (`sample`):

```
   gender   age partyID treatment_rand treatment_bias y_randT y_biasT
    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1       0    21       1              0              0       1       4
2       1    21       7              1              1       3       2
3       0    67       7              0              0       4       4
4       0    78       1              0              0       2       4
5       0    35       8              0              1       4       2
```

I use the subset of data:

```
X <- cbind(1, sample[, c("age", "partyID", "gender")])
choice_num <- 5
data_randT <- list(N=nrow(sample), D=ncol(X), t=sample$treatment_rand, X=X, y=sample$y_randT, K=choice_num)
```

My Stan code is:

```
data{
    int<lower=2> K;
    int<lower=0> N;
    int<lower=1> D;
    int<lower=1, upper=K> y[N];
    real<lower=0, upper=1> t[N];
    matrix[N,D] X;
}

parameters{
    vector[D] betaX;
    real betaT;
    ordered[K-1] c;
}

model{
    for(n in 1:N)
        y[n] ~ ordered_logistic(betaT*t[n] + X[n]*betaX, c);
}
```

If I run this code, I got the following error:

```
> fit_rand <- stan(model_code=stan_OrderedLogit, data=data_randT, seed=seed)
Error in new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) : 
  variable does not exist; processing stage=data initialization; variable name=X; base type=matrix_d
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : data with name X is not numeric and not used
failed to create the sampler; sampling not done
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will work if you make `X` a matrix in R, rather than a `data.frame`, as in

`X <- as.matrix(cbind(1, sample[, c("age", "partyID", "gender")]))`

However, I would think you you would first want to expand `partyID` into a set of dummy variables (excluding a reference category).